# I created a venv and tried to install tensorflow 1.15 but still the same error

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, python-venv, virtual-environment

Please Help me out.
I have installed tensorflow 2.3 globally and am trying to install tensorflow 1.15 but always face this error. I tried uninstalling tensor globally but failed.

```
(Cardiac) C:\venvCardiac>pip install tensorflow==1.15
Collecting tensorflow==1.15
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip Python3.8 is not compatible with Tensorflow 1.x but only with Tensorflow 2.x.

You should create a new python environment with an older python version (like 3.6.9) and then install Tensorflow 1.15 if that's what you need.

Comment: Does 3.7.12 support 1.x ? I read 3.7 supports but I got same error with 3.7 version

Answer (score -1):

For uninstalling tensorflow:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

Upgrade pip using this command:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Installing tensorflow 1.15 using this command:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15.0
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.